# How are link costs calculated from osm.pbf?

Tags: osm2po

I imported osm.pbf data into PostGIS using osm2po. The table I obtained (at_2po_4pgr) includes cost data. I would like to know how these costs have been calculated?

Answer (score 6):

```
public static double calcDistanceSphere(
        double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    // see: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
    double d = StrictMath.acos(StrictMath.sin(lat1 * RAD_PI) * StrictMath.sin(lat2 * RAD_PI)
            + StrictMath.cos(lat1 * RAD_PI)* StrictMath.cos(lat2 * RAD_PI)
            * StrictMath.cos((lon2-lon1) * RAD_PI))
            * RADIUS_EARTH_KM;
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) return 0;
    return d;
}



[km] = distanceSphere

cost[h] = [km] / [kmh]
```